# P4Python Adding new file - [Error]: Null directory (//) not allowed in //workspaceXXXX//xxxx.txt

Tags: python-2.7, perforce, p4python

I am trying to add new to perforce. I getting error as below

> [Error]: "Null directory (//) not allowed in '//workspaceXXXX//xxxx.txt'."

What i am doing:

1) I create a workspace

```
self.p4.client = "workspaceXXXX"
client = self.p4.fetch_client("workspaceXXXX")
client._root = "../temp/"workspaceXXXX""
depotPath = "//TEAM/PATH_1/PATH_2/2018-Aug-06/..."
wsPath = "//workspaceXXXX/..."
client._view = [depotPath+" "+wsPath] 
"""Create a workspace"""
self.p4.save_client(client)
```

2) Place the new in the workspace

3) Add file

```
self.p4.run("add", "//TEAM/PATH_1/PATH_2/2018-Aug-06/xxxx.txt")
```

While adding file i encounter the above error. What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: I think something got changed in the process of obfuscating your example -- the error references a client path, but you ran the command with a depot path.

Comment: Generally speaking, the "null directory" error means you constructed a bad path, sometimes due to either redundant or missing `/` characters in the client view.  I don't see any such mistakes in your obfuscated example, but I'm betting your real code has a typo.

Comment: @SamStafford i use almost the same code for check-in of edited file(file already in depot). Only change while creating workspace is, syn after self.p4.save_client(client) i.e self.p4.run_sync(depotFilePath)

Comment: @SamStafford yes >/ was missing in depotPath. In actual code it is dynamic value. Debugged the code properly found the problem. Thank you.